# Git Immersion Labs 16, Creating a Reverting Commit

Tags: git, vim

I'm having a lot of trouble creating a reverting commit. According to the instructions that I've followed (http://gitimmersion.com/lab_16.html), I made a change to a file and committed it, and am trying to revert that change by pushing another commit.

I typed in

```
git revert HEAD
```

where it mentions 
"This will pop you into the editor. You can edit the default commit message or leave it as is. Save and close the file. You should see …"

I'm not sure if this means I can pop into Sublime or just vim, but whenever I'm in vim I can't "save and close the file". I tried editing the comment and pressing `esc` + `:` `wq` + `return` but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you set your EDITOR environment variable in shell ?

Comment: vim was set automatically but even then i can't figure out how to "save and close" the changes in it. i dont know to change the default editor to sublime but im trying to look that up.

Comment: this is the syntax I am using for MacVim in my zshrc
`export EDITOR='mvim'`

If you want to use sublime you can use
`export EDITOR='subl'`
after creating a symlink in your path to Sublime executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure your editor:

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

(substituting `emacs` for `nano`, `pico` or something else you are familiar with).

The key sequence you want to save and exit from `vim` is `ESC` `:` `w` `q` `RETURN`. I realise that's pretty much what you wrote, but they way you wrote it, some of the keys had `+` between them implying you were pressing two keys at once (which won't work). In any case, better to use an editor you are happy with. Note that in many distributions, the default editor is *not* `vim` - though it looks a little like it - but some `nano` type thing, where (from memory, you want `^O` `X` or similar).